# How to get specific posts from Graph API

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm working on the Facebook Graph API in PHP.
I am currently getting all posts from a specific page using an URL from this form:
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/{user-id}/posts?access_token={token}

I'd like to only get the posts from the user,that means not the posts from the visitors that are published on the page. I can make a first sort by checking the story field but I still get posts I don't need.

How do I make the difference between these posts ?
Thanks for your help.

Edit: I was using the wrong endpoint /feed and not /posts as I thought I was. Finally works

Comment: `/page-id/posts` should only give you posts made by the page itself in the first place; posts by others on that page should only be included in `/page-id/feed`

Comment: Thanks it finally works this way. I was mistaking and was using the feed endpoint.

Comment: i thought you were talking about user profiles, not pages - since you wrote "user-id" in your api call. people often say pages when they actually mean user profiles.

Comment: I removed  - Resolved from the question title. Accepting a posted answer closes the question and marks it as solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no specific endpoint for this, so you have to do it on your own. You can use the "from" field to get the ID of the poster, just compare it to the ID of the authorized user:

```
me/posts?fields=message,from
```

If you are talking about Pages (not User Profiles), then `/page-id/posts` will deliver posts made by the Page anyway.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I found out I made a simple mistake.
Hopefully this will help someone else.